# How to speed up this query with mysql_num_rows?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have 2 DBs. One is in my main host(Forums-Site) and the other one is for other info. The reason why I'm using the other DB is because my host doesn't allow remote connections. So I'm forced to try this way for now.

I want to simply write this code better. By better I'm talking about, is this the correct way to use it if I want to make another connection and if it can be optimized, please let me know how.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("Host", "User", "Pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DB", $connection);

$gs_kdq = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Kills) AS g_killz, SUM(Deaths) AS g_deathz FROM Users", $connection);
$gs_kd = mysql_fetch_assoc($gs_kdq);

$gs_players = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$gs_Something0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Something0", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$gs_Something1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Something1", $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$gs_Something2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Something2", $connection) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_num_rows($gs_players);
mysql_num_rows($gs_Something0);
mysql_num_rows($gs_Something1);
mysql_num_rows($gs_Something2);
```

Forums load a bit slow because of (I think) mysql_num_rows.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you should use mysqli_ or PDO, mysql_ seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Yeah Nadir, was reading about PDO earlier. Forgot to mention it in my post. Will change it to use that format.

Answer (score 6):

You're reading all of the data from your tables just to find out how big they are. SQL has [a much faster way of doing this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable
```

This will return one result with the number of rows in that table (you can add a `WHERE` clause and it will return the number that match).

Comment: Thanks! I just knew there was a better way but didn't know were to start from.

Comment: @user1667191 For getting started, I'd recommend taking a look at [the documentation for SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html), for example [aggregate functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html). The language is almost identical to MySQL's dialect, but the documentation is better written and much shorter, which should help get an overview of what's possible. If something doesn't work how you'd expect, you can always do a Google search for `mysql $thing_i_dont_understand`.